# How to produce a short unique id in php?

Tags: php

In order to produce a unique Id I suppose I must use the uniqid function in php.
But uniqid produces a 13 digits long HEXA number, by default.

```
4f66835b507db
```

I would like to reduce this number to 7 digits long NUMERIC number but I want to conserve the unicity. Is it possible ?

```
4974012
```

This number will be used as User Id. The authentication will be done with thid Id and a password.

Some people say uniqid is not unique ! Is it a bad choice ?

Comment: define "unique" to your application? just to have an id that isn't like `1,2,3,4` ?

Comment: If you are storing users in a DB, then why don't you just let the DB handle it?

Comment: If your script is launched one time for each users, then you lose unicity...

Comment: @jakub: unique = never repeated, not easy to guess

Comment: Unique and short at the same time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is not guaranteed to be unique, even in its full length.

Furthermore, uniqid is intended to be unique only **locally**. This means that if you create users simultaneously on two or more servers, you may end up with one ID for two different users, **even if you use full-length uniqid**.

My recommendations:

- If you are really looking for **globally** unique identifiers (i.e. your application is running on multiple servers with separate databases), you should use [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). These are even longer than the ones returned by uniqid, but there is no practical chance of collisions.
- If you need only **locally** unique identifiers, stick with AUTO_INCREMENT in your database. This is (a little) faster and (a little) safer than checking if a short random ID already exists in your database.

**EDIT:** As it turns out in the comments below, you are looking not only for an ID for the user, but rather you are forced to provide your users with a random login name... Which is weird, but okay. In such case, you may try to use `rand` in a loop, until you get one that does not exist in your database.

Pseudocode:

```
$min = 1;
do {
    $username = "user" . rand($min, $min * 10);
    $min = $min * 10;
} while (user_exists($username));
// Create your user here.
```

Comment: The auto-increment gives an "easy to know" number: not dangerous ?

Comment: IDs, by definition, are not "secret". Unless some big programming error on your part, knowing IDs of different users shouldn't do attackers any good.

Comment: Then Id + password is enough ?

Comment: Usually, users don't login with artificial numeric IDs, this is considered to be a bad user experience. Users are allowed to pick their own username at registration or - even better - they login with their email address. Login/Username fields, altough also unique, usually have nothing to do with IDs. They have different functionallity.

Comment: Autoincremented values will give away two things: 1) with a userid 100 you can assume that not many users exist  2) with a userid 12345 one can assume that another user with id 12344 exists too. This can be a problem or not, but normally there is no need to show the id to the user.

Comment: Imagine I have in my database factoryId,user,password,id for each employee. I could have two employees with the same user and the same password (but not he same id). For the login procedure, user and password are not enough to identify the employee. That's way I envisaged to use id instead of user. But if you have the answer to this dilemma ...

Comment: The best solution is to use email address as a login - this is always unique and every user knows it. Second best - make your "user" column unique. Your users won't be happy if forced to login with an artificial ID.

Comment: Unfortunately my application doesn't handle the email (because unuseful). When I login on my account of my bank, I am using an Id (happy or not happy, I don't have the choice).

Comment: Well, if you really can't think of any better identifier for your users, then use `rand(100000, 999999)`. Remember to check in the database if it already exists, before assigning it to the new user.

Comment: I edited my answer above to include this particular scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Any "unique" number will eventually have a collision after generating enough records. To ensure uniqueness, you need to store the values you generated into a database and when generating next one, you need to check if there is no collision.

However, in practice, applications usually generate IDs as a simple sequence 1,2,3,... That way you know you won't get a collision until you run out of the datatype (UINT is usually 32 bits long, which gives you 4 billion unique ids).

Answer (score 1):

Write a while loop that generates random letters and numbers of a desired length, which loops until it creates an ID that is not already in use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by reducing it to 7 characters and only numeric, you are reducing the 'uniqueness' by a lot.

I suggest using an auto increment of the user ID and start at 1000000 if it has to be 7 digits long.

If you really must generate it without auto increment, you can use `mt_rand()` to generate a random number 7 digits long:

```
$random = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
```

This is not ideal because you will need to check if the number is already in use by another user.

Comment: you should do `str_pad(mt_rand(0, 9999999), 7, 0);` instead. That allows for a larger number of random numbers.

Comment: @Chrules, you're right but auto increment is still generally better if with the additional numbers from str_pad. Also keep in mind `0000001` is not IMO a good user ID, it will be truncated to `1` in some cases e.g. `(int)$userId`

Comment: Unless he stored it as a string, but anyways, did not disagree with the auto increment, It would be a much more natural way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a lookt at this article

- [Create short IDs with PHP - Like Youtube or TinyURL](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/06/10/create-short-ids-with-php-like-youtube-or-tinyurl)

It explains how to generate short unique ids, like youtube does.

Actually, the function in the article is very related to [php function base_convert](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.base-convert.php) which converts a number from a base to another (but is only up to base 36).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Database. Define an `id` column as `unique` and `auto-incremented`, and then let the database manage your ids.

It's safer.

Read more : [mysql-doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: So, if you want a hard to guess, @mitchsatchwell solution look good